# ¿Como traer campos de tablas relacionadas con Eloquent PHP laravel?

Tags: php, api, eloquent, select

estoy creando un api en PHP Laravel, yo ya vengo de C# y Entity Framework pero hay cosas que aun no entiendo como funcionan en laravel.

tengo esta consulta:

```
People::with('user','rol','state','tower','apartament')->get()
```

y me trae esta información:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "User1",
            "last_name": "lnUser1",
            "phone": 3132835875,
            "img_profile": null,
            "floor": 4,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "email": "user1@dev.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": "2022-04-26T03:12:03.000000Z"
            },
            "rol": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Administrador"
            },
            "state": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Activo"
            },
            "tower": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "A"
            },
            "apartament": {
                "id": 116,
                "name": "1206"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "User2",
            "last_name": "lnUser2",
            "phone": 3132835875,
            "img_profile": null,
            "floor": 2,
            "user": {
                "id": 2,
                "email": "user2@dev.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "rol": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Moderador"
            },
            "state": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Inactivo"
            },
            "tower": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "A"
            },
            "apartament": {
                "id": 116,
                "name": "1206"
            }
        }
]
```

una lista de usuarios. pero yo necesito mostrar solo un par de datos no todo. asi que arme esta consulta asi:

```
People::with('user','rol','state','tower','apartament')->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(name, " ", last_name) as name, phone, img_profile, floor'))->get()
```

y me trae esta respuesta:

```
[
{
            "name": "User1 lnUser1",
            "phone": 3132835875,
            "img_profile": null,
            "floor": 4,
            "user": null,
            "rol": null,
            "state": null,
            "tower": null,
            "apartament": null
        },
        {
            "name": "User2 lnUser2",
            "phone": 3132835875,
            "img_profile": null,
            "floor": 2,
            "user": null,
            "rol": null,
            "state": null,
            "tower": null,
            "apartament": null
        }
]
```

He buscado y averiguado pero en todas las ocasiones me genera error o problemas con el query.

Asi que no se como seleccionar solamente el/los campos específicos de las tablas relacionadas (user, rol,state, tower y apartament). necesito una respuesta que me venga así:

```
[
    {
        "name": "User1 lnUser1",
        "phone": 3132835875,
        "img_profile": null,
        "floor": 4,
        "user_email": "user1@dev.com",
        "rol_name": "Administrador",
        "state_name": "Activo",
        "tower_name": "A",
        "apartament_number": "1206"
    },
    {
        "name": "User2 lnUser2",
        "phone": 3132835875,
        "img_profile": null,
        "floor": 2,
        "user_email": "user2@dev.com",
        "rol_name": "Moderador",
        "state_name": "Inactivo",
        "tower_name": "A",
        "apartament_number": "1206"
    }
]
```

Comment: para lo que dices lo mejor es crear una vista, luego llamas a esa vista "con los campos ya definidos" creando un nuevo modelo. eso es lo mejorcito, ahora lo que [tu necesitas es un join](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins), usa la documentacion y ve uno que otro tutorial, es facil entrar en el mundillo de laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si requieres  algo mas  complejo y deseas utlizar una consulta mas  simple puedes usar querybuilder de laravel  un ejemplo aqui con un join

```
          DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

Comment: perfecto, este fue el que termine usando para mi consulta, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Para obtener únicamente ciertas columnas puedes utilizar el método [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck)

Ejemplo:

```
People::pluck('user','rol','state','tower','apartament')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar accesors para crear campos del modelo Eloquent, por ejemplo:

```
public function getRolNameAttribute {
    return $this->rol->name;
}
```

Esto hace que puedas acceder al campo name de rol desde una instancia de People: `$somePeople->rol_name`. [Aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) puedes leer mas sobre los accesors.

Luego de definir tus accesors para los campos que quieres añadir a la respuesta, los añades a la propiedad `$appends` de la clase modelo, esto hace que esos campos sean añadidos a las respuestas del modelo:

```
 protected $appends = ['rol_name', 'state_name', 'tower_name'];
```